# Can I use a StreamReader to read from a file in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, streamreader

I'm trying to read in some sample data from an XML file in a Silverlight project, and this line:

```
using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\mike\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\test\test\Data\test.xml"))
```

Throws this exception:

> System.MethodAccessException: Attempt
>   to access the method failed:
>   System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(System.String)
>
> --- Inner Exception --- Attempt to
>   access the method failed:
>   System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(System.String)

I'm positive that the path is correct, I copied it out of explorer (pasting the filename at the end) to be sure.

What might cause this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Silverlight runs in a different security context enforced by browsers. You cannot access the file system at your will. Image if you can, some one can write a silverlight program that deletes users files once the web page is opened.

Comment: Okay. Can you recommend a way to do this, then? I just have a big block of XML in a file that I want to read in, just as a test. I'd hardcode it, but the quotes in the XML terminate the string.

Comment: Curt Nichols already gave the hint. Yes, OpenFileDialog is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to look into [OpenFileDialog](http://www.silverlightexamples.net/post/Open-File-Dialog-in-Silverlight.aspx) if you want to open a file in Silverlight.

Answer (score 1):

You can only `StreamRead` a file from SilverLight if it's on the server.

Comment: I read that while trying to figure this out, but isn't my computer the server when I'm just running from Visual Studio?